# Mapping a big dataframe to calculate

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a table like this:

```
   account_id   costs
a                 1
b       1         2
c_________________3
d                 90
e       2         50
f_________________30
```

I'm trying to calculate another column, called total costs, with something like this:

```
final["total_costs"] = final["account_id"].map(calculate_balance)

def calculate_balance (x):
    balance.append(final[final.account_id == x].costs.cumsum())
```

But it's taking TOO LONG. Can i use another solution? Much faster?

Comment: Are you looking for cumulative sum grouped by account_id? So 1, 3, 6, 90, 140, 170?

Comment: yes, i am, but i donw know how

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.groupby` to calculate the values fast (and just once per group), and then `.map` to write them back to your new column.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

final = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
   account_id   costs
a       1         1
b       1         2
c       1         3
d       2         90
e       2         50
f       2         30"""), sep="\s+")

final["total_costs"] = final.groupby("account_id").cumsum()['costs']

print(final)
```

Output:

```
   account_id  costs  total_costs
a           1      1            1
b           1      2            3
c           1      3            6
d           2     90           90
e           2     50          140
f           2     30          170
```

Comment: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` with `cumsum` function:

```
final['total_costs'] = final.groupby('account_id').cumsum()['costs']
```

Results:

```
   account_id  costs  total_costs
0           1      1            1
1           1      2            3
2           1      3            6
3           2     90           90
4           2     50          140
5           2     30          170
```

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

Comment: Maybe your real DataFrame has more columns. See edit and it should work now.